# Watching specific HTTP Requests

Tags: httpwatch

for work purposes I need to analyse a very large number of Javascript tags which produces numerous requests over HTTP.
I normally load these scripts on a local web page and then run Fiddler to see if the right requests are made.
Since the work is getting busier I would like to automate this process and make a tool where to put my N scripts, set what to check on the UI and get an output where I'm told "Everything as planned" or "Something is not right."
The things I usually check on these http requests are:

- presence of requests to various (and foretold) hosts
- string analysis of these requests if found

Is there a tool out there where I can do this kind of task or do I have to build one from scratch?
I know fiddler has plugin support, maybe I can do one suitable for me?

If I'm going to build the tool from scratch, what language/method do you advise to me?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using the HttpWatch automation interface:

http://apihelp.httpwatch.com/

- Disclaimer: This answer was provided by Simtec Limited the makers of HttpWatch *